# python The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() in q-learning

Tags: python, q-learning

`

```
def state_to_bucket(state):
    bucket_indice = []
    for i in range(len(state)):
        max_bucket = NUM_BUCKETS[i] - 1
        minimum = STATE_BOUNDS[i][0]
        maximum = STATE_BOUNDS[i][1]
        state_value = state[i]
        if state_value <= minimum:
            bucket_index = 0
        elif state_value >= maximum:
            bucket_index = max_bucket
        else:
            # Mapping the state bounds to the bucket array. bucket_index*(min-max normalized state)
            bound_width = maximum - minimum
            bucket_index = int(round(max_bucket*(state_value - minimum)/bound_width))
        bucket_indice.append(bucket_index)
    return tuple(bucket_indice)
```

`

this is a part of q-learning code, called Bucketing function
but i got error

`

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [43], line 1
----> 1 simulate()

Cell In [42], line 15, in simulate()
     12 obv = env.reset()
     14 # the initial state
---> 15 state_0 = state_to_bucket(obv)
     17 for t in range(MAX_TIMESTEP):
     18     env.render(mode='ansi')

Cell In [41], line 4, in state_to_bucket(state)
      2 bucket_indice = []
      3 for i in range(len(state)):
----> 4     if state[i] <= STATE_BOUNDS[i][0]:
      5         bucket_index = 0
      6     elif state[i] >= STATE_BOUNDS[i][1]:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`

i don't know why.. somebody let me know the right code please!

reference : https://www.kaggle.com/code/just4jcgeorge/q-learning-openai-gym-cartpole/notebook

Comment: Your `obv` should be an array. It is a list of arrays now, which means, that `state[i]` is an array, which leads to the error.

Comment: then, should i add `obv = np.array(obv)` ?

Comment: no, then it will be a 2d array, and the error will still be there. You have to understand the code and get why `obv` is now not what it has to be